# Can't install nautilus-dropbox on Centos 8

Tags: dropbox, rpm, yum, centos8

I try to install dropbox on Centos8, however Terminal gives strange errors. Tried different commands, same error.

Firstly downloaded *.rpm file from dropbox website, currently trying to install it.

Commands I tried:

`rpm -ivh nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04-1.fedora.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04-1.fedora.x86_64.rpm`

Error:

`Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:27 ago on Thu 12 Mar 2020 03:46:17 PM EET
Error: 
Problem: conflicting requests 
nothing provides libgnome >= %{gnome_version} needed by nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04-1.fc21.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@localhost Downloads]`

Also tried `--skip-broken` and `--nobest` - but no luck.

Also tried `sudo yum install libgnome` but it gives error:

`Last metadata expiration check: 9:51:39 ago on Thu 12 Mar 2020 02:42:06 PM UTC.
No match for argument: libgnome
Error: Unable to find a match: libgnome`

I have:

`[adminuser@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)`

Tried to google this mistake, but no luck. Could you please give me any hint how I could overcome this?

Thank you

Comment: Available for CentOS 8 is : python3-dropbox → in the EPEL repo ( https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/p/ ) ..... EPEL : `dnf install epel-release`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in packaging. Contact Dropbox support and report it as a bug.

Technical details (just in case you are Dropbox employee):
During building rpm, when you use macro then it is expanded. Try yoursel:

```
$ rpm --eval '%{_bindir}'
/usr/bin
```

However, when the macro is not defined, you get original value:

```
$ rpm --eval '%{some_bullshit}'
%{some_bullshit}
```

So the macro `gnome_version` should likely contain some version, but this macro was not defined.

Comment: msuchy → https://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/31/x86_64/ . The package is OK. Installs into all  Fedora versions 20 - 31. Fedora has libgnome-2.3x support  ... CentOS8 : "nothing provides libgnome". I.e. CentOS 8 has no libgnome2 support.

Answer (score 0):

> nothing provides libgnome

"libgnome" is about libgnome-2 → https://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/ → I.e. *Fedora only packages*. CentOS 8 has no libgnome* available.

---

https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux → Compile from source → CentOS 8

```
# dnf install nautilus-devel-3.28.1-10.el8.x86_64 python3-docutils

tar xvf nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04.tar.bz2
cd nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04/
./configure && make
# make install
```

Result : `nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AcxlVdbWOzQvcoVOFYCiaVny9MzgC-Ea/view?usp=sharing

`# rpm -Uvh nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04-1.el8.x86_64.rpm` : No issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, realize that the command showing at [the install page](https://www.dropbox.com/install) is for the *headless* installation. It will probably work, but my preference is to use Dropbox with nautilus integration.

This instructions assumes a installation of Dropbox with Nautilus integration.

1. We need to compile [the installer from source](https://www.dropbox.com/help/247).

a. Download [last package](https://linux.dropbox.com/packages/)

```
wget https://linux.dropbox.com/packages/nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04.tar.bz2
```

b. Extract tarball

```
tar xjf ./nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04.tar.bz2
```

c. Try to compile

```
cd nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04; ./configure;
```

Then you get an Error:

```
Erro: 
 Problema: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libgnome >= %{gnome_version} needed by nautilus-dropbox-2020.03.04-1.fc21.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Now we need to install [nautilus-devel](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/nautilus-devel-3.28.1-12.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) and python3-docutils

NOTE: You will get `configure: error: couldn't find docutils` if forget `python3-docutils`.

This command will enable the PowerTools repository and install what is needed:

```
    dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install nautilus-devel python3-docutils
```

Now you can run `./configure && sudo make install`

2. That's it. Go for the start menu type "Dropbox", it will start the installer.
3. Restore a local backup of Dropbox (optional)

If you have a local backup, turn of the network after you see the `Dropbox` folder created. Then copy all your files to that folder and turn it on after copy.

[image]

This solution worked for me running `CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)`.